# SQL IF ELSE WITH MULTIPLE SELECT STATEMENT

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement

I want to optimize these SQL queries using if-else but how I should use it? .
if this query result contain 'ALL'

```
SELECT
bdsubcategory.subcategoryID as ID,
bdsubcategory.subcategoryName as Name
FROM
phonebook.newsms_subscription
INNER JOIN bdsubcategory ON bdsubcategory.subcategoryID = newsms_subscription.subcategoryID
INNER JOIN newsms_client ON newsms_subscription.clientID =newsms_client.clientID
INNER JOIN newsms_person ON newsms_subscription.personID = newsms_person.personID
WHERE
newsms_subscription.isActive = 1 AND
newsms_person.personID = '856'
```

Then i want to query this

```
SELECT
bdsubcategory.subcategoryID as ID,
bdsubcategory.subcategoryName as Name
FROM
phonebook.newsms_subscription
INNER JOIN bdsubcategory ON bdsubcategory.subcategoryID = newsms_subscription.subcategoryID
INNER JOIN newsms_person ON newsms_subscription.personID = newsms_person.personID
WHERE
newsms_subscription.isActive = 1
GROUP BY subcategoryName
ORDER BY subcategoryName
```

otherwise take query1 result .

Comment: As above suggestions will depend on which specific RDBMS you are using.

Comment: I am using MySQL . I have to optimize this query for my application API.

Comment: Specifically what do you mean by `if this query result contain 'ALL'`? Use examples as well as descriptions.

Comment: This means if this query result gets 'ALL' in output.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that if we do not refactor your project, then you always have to evaluate query1 and see whether it contains All or not. If it does not contain All, then you need to evaluate query2 as well. This can hardly be optimized, let's see a few approaches:

### Quickening query1

Since All might be not be the very last evaluated element, adding it to the filter and limiting it is a good idea to quicken query1:

```
SELECT
COUNT(*)
FROM
phonebook.newsms_subscription
INNER JOIN bdsubcategory ON bdsubcategory.subcategoryID = newsms_subscription.subcategoryID
INNER JOIN newsms_client ON newsms_subscription.clientID =newsms_client.clientID
INNER JOIN newsms_person ON newsms_subscription.personID = newsms_person.personID
WHERE
newsms_subscription.isActive = 1 AND
newsms_person.personID = '856' AND
bdsubcategory.subcategoryName = 'ALL'
LIMIT 0, 1
```

So, you could create a stored procedure which evaluates query1' (query1' is the quickened version of query1, as seen above) and if there is a result, then we need to execute query1. Otherwise we need to execute query2. This way you still execute two queries, but the first query is optimized.

## Refactoring

Note that the second query does not change. You could create a `table` where you could cache its results, using a periodic job. Then, you could skip the second table to

```
SELECT ID, Name
FROM MyNewTable;
```

without the many joins. You would also cache the results of the first query into a table where the items having ALL would be stored and query that table.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use a `CASE`.

Change this:

```
newsms_person.personID = '856'
```

To this:

```
'Y' = CASE WHEN UPPER('856') = 'ALL' THEN 'Y'
           WHEN newsms_person.personID = '856' THEN 'Y'
           ELSE 'N' END
```

Alternatively, a stored procedure could be used to first validate whether the `personID` seems valid, then returns the appropriate data.